# Streaming to silverlight/flash

Tags: c#, silverlight, flash, streaming, vlc

I have a VLC player streaming my webcam video through RTSP on 5544 port, the video is encapsulated with MPEG-TS and compressed with MPEG-4 for both audio and video (as is VLC's default I suppose)

You can access the streaming video with the following URL:

http://100.100.100.100:5544/

where 100.100.100.100 is my ip.

All is working till here. I could also change transport protocol/incapsulation, that's not a problem since VLC allows me to do it.

I want to develop a silverlight player (preferred) or a flash player capable of reproducing the stream (audio and video).
I don't know how to do this.

The question is: I could not find a link on the internet on how reproducing a VLC stream with a silverlight(preferred) or flash applet in a web page

Since I'm not a Silverlight/Flash developer I'll appreciate code samples, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these 2 app's could help you .
http://www.wowzamedia.com/
http://www.red5.org/

Comment: Thank you but they can't be useful, I already knew of them but I need for a specific bandwidth reason to code my application myself.